# Jenkins is marking job as unstable, when there are failures in the test suite

Tags: java, jenkins

For context, I'm using the following stack: Java, Selenium, TestNG, Allure Report, Maven, Jenkins.
As the title says, Jenkins is marking the job as unstable, when there are failures (not broken tests) in the test suite.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this is the expected behaviour?
Other testing frameworks such as Playwright, mark the job as "Failed" when there are failures in the report/test suite.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is expected behavior.

As per the [Jenkins Glossary](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#unstable):

**Unstable**:
The Build had some errors but they were not fatal. A Build is unstable if it was built successfully and one or more publishers report it unstable. For example if the JUnit publisher is configured and a test fails then the Build will be marked unstable.